# ubuntu setting system variables

Tags: 14.04, server, xubuntu

I am trying to protect my server as below system variables

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
# IP Spoofing protection
​net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1
​net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1
#Ignore ICMP broadcast requests
​net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=1
# Disable source packet routing
​net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route=0
​net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route=0 
​net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route=0
​net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_source_route=0
# Ignore send redirects
​net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0
​net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects=0
# Block SYN attacks
​net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
​net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=2048
​net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries=2
​net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries=5
# Log Martians
​net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians=1
​net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses=1
# Ignore ICMP redirects
​net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects=0
​net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects=0
​net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects=0 
​net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects=0
# Ignore Directed pings
​net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
```

Image:

[image]

But I get some error happen when I applied the rules.

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_source_route: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_source_route: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/conf/default/accept_source_route: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv6/conf/default/accept_source_route: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/conf/all/send_redirects: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/conf/default/send_redirects: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/tcp_synack_retries: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/conf/all/log_martians: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_redirects: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/conf/default/accept_redirects: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv6/conf/default/accept_redirects: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/​net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all: No such file or directory
```

Error images: 
[image]

Here  cat -A /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1$
# IP Spoofing protection$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1$
#Ignore ICMP broadcast requests$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=1$
# Disable source packet routing$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route=0$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route=0$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route=0$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv6.conf.default.accept_source_route=0$
# Ignore send redirects$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects=0$
# Block SYN attacks$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=2048$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries=2$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries=5$
# Log Martians$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians=1$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses=1$
# Ignore ICMP redirects$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects=0$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects=0$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects=0$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects=0$
# Ignore Directed pings$
M-bM-^@M-^Knet.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1$
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-lon1-01:/etc#
```

Comment: Do those files exist and how are you changing these values? Please remove the spaces between the `variables` and `=` and `value`!

Comment: I did not change those I check on rp_filter file I see 1 numer value eixsting there but 
I don't know why I get those error messages

Comment: Remove the spaces and see if the error goes away! Let this `net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1` be this `net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=1`.

Comment: You mean remove the space between one block to another block right
example: # Block SYN attacks to # Log Martians right?

Comment: No let me post a simple answer so you can follow! And are you adding them manuallly or from a script?

Comment: Note that the *images* actually show that the missing files are `/proc/sys/ net/xxx` (with some kind of non-printing character before the `net`) - I suspect there is something messed up in your editor settings - can you show us the output of `cat -A /etc/sysctl.conf` please?

Comment: I found this M-bM-^@M-^K maybe from editor

Comment: That's not right! How are you adding these keys, from a script or?

Comment: Ok It work well now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1
```

Change each line so no spaces exists between variables and the values, like so

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=1
```

Comment: I update new one as you see i update the question but still the same error

Comment: ... `man sysctl.conf` says *"whitespace before  and  after  a  token  or  value  is  ignored"* though?

Comment: I update error output please help to check it and those setting I try to clean space also but pass it to some text editor.

Comment: Let me try to track down the error!